# How can I set up top border radius for the columns in Column chart in highcharts js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vuejs3

[image: 1]

I get it this way

[image: 2]

It should be like this

My code

```
plotOptions: {
                   column: {
                      maxPointWidth: 36,
                      stacking: 'normal'
                   },
                   series: {
                      borderRadius: 5
                   }
            }
```

Is it possible to do this without any plugins?

Comment: At this time, you can achieve this only via the plugin. However, this feature has been added to our development workflow and will be develope soon. Ticket to track: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17368.

Comment: Thanks, Magdalena! Installed the plugin and it worked. let's hope it gets resolved soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-border-radius?activeTab=readme plugin.

```
plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    maxPointWidth: 36,
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
 series: [
              {
                  name: 'Valid',
                  data: [],
                  color: '#5185F3',
                  borderRadiusTopLeft: 5,
                  borderRadiusTopRight: 5
              },
              {
                  id: 'failed',
                  name: 'Failed Verification',
                  data: [],
                  color: '#FF4949'
              },
              {
                  linkedTo: 'failed',
                  borderRadiusTopLeft: 5,
                  borderRadiusTopRight: 5
              }
          ]
```

**Result:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdbZA.png)